# Send int value to my http server from a Spinner in android

Tags: android

```
pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", gender.getSelectedItem()
                    .toString()));
```

How can I fix this? I need to send an int value to my database from the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", Integer.parseInt(gender.getSelectedItem() .toString())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert String to int and after add integer value into pair, it will solve your problem.

```
String s=gender.getSelectedItem().toString();
int i=Integer.parseInt(s);
pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", i));
```